# Caption of figure with tikz-mindmap won't appear under the tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, mindmaps

I am using the following code to generate a mindmap on a single A3 page that is included in a usual A4 formatted paper. I want the caption to be under the whole mindmap, but apparently it is being placed below the first set node. I assume this is because of the options "remember picture" and "overlay" that I use to place the starting node in a certain position. Therefore some child nodes happen to be below the caption. How do I get the caption to really be belowthe whole mindmap?

My code:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,%a4 Papier
11pt, %schriftgroesse
BCOR=12mm, %binding correction
DIV=11,
twoside, %doppelseitig 
openright, %erstes kapitel steht rechts
cleardoublepage=plain, %Leere Seiten werden nummeriert (wegen openright)
parskip=half-
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc,math,angles,quotes,trees,mindmap}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=small}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\paragraph{Mindmap}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,DIV=23,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style={concept,font=\small,minimum size=0cm}, concept color=gray!60, 
    level 1/.append style={font=\footnotesize, level distance=4cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append style={font=\footnotesize,level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45},
    level 3/.append style={font=\footnotesize,level distance=3cm,sibling angle=37},
    level 4/.append style={font=\footnotesize,level distance=2.5cm,sibling angle=50},
    level 5/.append style={font=\footnotesize,level distance=2cm,sibling angle=40}]
    \node[xshift=2.5cm,yshift=2cm,inner sep=0cm] at (current page.center) (mac) {First node}
    child { node  {Second node}
    [level 2/.append style={sibling angle=60}] 
    [level 3/.append style={sibling angle=45}] 
    [level 4/.append style={sibling angle=30}] 
        child { node  {Third node}
            child { node[xshift=0.5cm]  (Macsup) {Child}}
            child { node[xshift=-0cm,yshift=2.5cm]  {Child}}
        }
        child { node[xshift=-1cm]  (Macro) {Third node}
            child { node[xshift=-2cm,yshift=3cm]  (Qubits) {Text}}  
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Mindmap.}
\label{mindmap}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=portrait,DIV=11}
\recalctypearea
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer by myself, I will still keep the question if somebody else needs similar help. I got rid of "overlay" in the tikzpicture options. Apparently this option makes the picture itself not need any space - this made the caption appear in the middle of the page as if there was no picture at all.

Comment: If you wait a day or so, you can accept your own answer and close the question.